# How do I exclude directory with find + grep?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, directory, find

In Bash I'm trying to find a string across multiple scattered files.

I get thousands of errors from grep accessing /sys which I'm trying to exclude:

```
find / -type f ! -path "/sys" -exec grep -l StringToFind {} \;
find / -type f -exec grep -l --exclude-dir="/sys" StringToFind {} \;
```

Can somebody explain why neither of the above work?
I tried a couple of other variations with grep -v and egrep with no success.

How about excluding multiple directories and patterns?

Comment: is it possible you need to pipe into grep? i.e. `find / -type f ! -path "/sys" -exec | grep -l StringToFind {} \;`

Comment: No Michael as exec needs an argument.

Comment: Try this `find / -type f -exec grep string "{}" \; -o -name "/sys" -prune`

Comment: Still no joy Mark - 2 warnings from "find".

When I remove " – " after "prune" then "grep" still examines /sys and complains.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Close, but `-name` takes a file `-path` takes a path.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with

`-path "/sys"`

- You're providing the absolute path to `find`, which is only true for the exact directory (or file) `/sys` and not true for any subdirectories. If you wanted it to be true for anything below `/sys`, it should have been `-path "/sys/*"` or `! -path "/sys" ! -path "/sys/*` (for both)
- `-path` does no stop `-find` from traversing a directory, so you can still get errors for files below it

Try

```
find / -path "/sys" -prune -o -type f -exec grep -l StringToFind {} +
```

Or better yet (your `--exclude-dir` fails for  a similar reason to `-find`, since it's non-recursive you're ecluding only the exact argument `/sys` -- which `find` never passes to it anyway)

```
grep -r -l --exclude-dir="/sys" StringToFind /
```